# Django Error Message: You can't set team_name (a non-nullable field) to None

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am trying to extend userprofile with column from another model as Foreign key. But, while saving its throwing error message.

```
Models.py:

class Team_Profile(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    
    
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team_Profile)


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            existing = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.user)
            self.id = existing.id
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Below is my views.py:

## Views.py:

```
data = request.POST.copy()
team = data['team_hidden']
try:
            team_name = Team_Profile.objects.get(team_name=team)
except Team_Profile.DoesNotExist:
            team_profile = Team_Profile()
            team_profile.team_name = team
            team_profile.save()
                
try:
            user=User.objects.get(username=name)
            return render_to_response("user_exist.html", {'media_url':media_url})
            
except User.DoesNotExist:

            user= User.objects.create_user(name,User.email,User.password)
            user.first_name=first_name
            user.last_name=last_name
            user.save()

                        
            userprofile = UserProfile()
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.team_name = Team_Profile.objects.get(team_name=team)                    


            userprofile.save()
```

Let me know if you need more info. Any help is appreciated.

## Traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/myentrancetest/views.py" in create_login
  796.          user= User.objects.create_user(name,User.email,User.password)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  135.         user.save(using=self._db)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  592.                 created=created, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/myentrancetest/models.py" in create_user_profile
  53.         created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/manager.py" in get_or_create
  135.         return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  387.                 obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/myentrancetest/models.py" in save
  49.       models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  571.                     result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  195.         return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1437.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/dbindexer/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  256.         return super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(return_id=return_id)
File "/home/dtechsun/testapp/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in execute_sql
  348.                                         "field) to None!" % field.name)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /create_login/
Exception Value: You can't set team_name (a non-nullable field) to None!
```

Thanks,

Sunil

Comment: Can you post the entire error trace? (Sorry for posting as an answer initially.)

Comment: Sorry patrickn.This one is for my hobby project and code is available at my local system. Currently I am at work and the whole traceback I can provide only after 02 hour when I'll leave for home. But, in traceback its showing following line where control is halting: user= User.objects.create_user(name,User.email,User.password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding default for team_name worked fine. Thanks everyone for your help.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)   
        team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team_Profile, default=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your overall logic seems correct. But, i think the error seems to be happening in the first except block at

`team_profile.team_name = team`
team is coming out to be None at this point, I think, which would throw an error on saving in the next line. So check for the values you get from the request.

Comment: Actually, team name is coming properly and getting stored in Team_Profile model.

Comment: I saw the stack trace right now. Error is occurring at user creation, is what it is saying. What is User.email and User.password? It seems wrong.

Comment: If I am not including Team related information, everything is working absolutely fine. So, I don't think there is any problem with user creation. User.email and User.password is the values coming from template into views.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here lies in that you've got UserProfile as a OneToOneField mapping with the User model. Django is expecting a non-null value for team_name, because it's got a relationship with the UserProfile model. Try setting the team_name when you create your User and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, atleast now I know the reason why its happening. But I am  not getting how and where I should add Team name. I am tweaking the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

`User.objects.create_user` will create/save an `User` instance and thus trigger the `create_user_profile` to execute. Then it would fail when there is not matched `UserProfile` instance:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # team_name is None, 
        # but UserProfile.team_name is declared w/ null=False, by default
        created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Yes, I think this may be the reason. Any way we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because :

```
team = data['team_hidden']
```

team may be empty (no team_hidden was sent during post, or it was a get request...)